# How to use ``xlrd.xldate_as_tuple()``

Tags: python, date, xlrd

I am not quite sure how to use the following function:

```
xlrd.xldate_as_tuple
```

for the following data

```
xldate:39274.0
xldate:39839.0
```

Could someone please give me an example on usage of the function for the data?

Comment: link: https://classic.scraperwiki.com/docs/python/python_excel_guide/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Quoth [the documentation](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html):

> ### Dates in Excel spreadsheets
>
> In reality, there are no such things.
>   What you have are floating point
>   numbers and pious hope. There are
>   several problems with Excel dates:
>
> (1) Dates are not stored as a separate
>   data type; they are stored as floating
>   point numbers and you have to rely on
>   (a) the "number format" applied to
>   them in Excel and/or (b) knowing which
>   cells are supposed to have dates in
>   them. This module helps with (a) by
>   inspecting the format that has been
>   applied to each number cell; if it
>   appears to be a date format, the cell
>   is classified as a date rather than a
>   number. Feedback on this feature,
>   especially from non-English-speaking
>   locales, would be appreciated.
>
> (2) Excel for Windows stores dates by
>   default as the number of days (or
>   fraction thereof) since
>   1899-12-31T00:00:00. Excel for
>   Macintosh uses a default start date of
>   1904-01-01T00:00:00. The date system
>   can be changed in Excel on a
>   per-workbook basis (for example: Tools
>   -> Options -> Calculation, tick the "1904 date system" box). This is of
>   course a bad idea if there are already
>   dates in the workbook. There is no
>   good reason to change it even if there
>   are no dates in the workbook. Which
>   date system is in use is recorded in
>   the workbook. A workbook transported
>   from Windows to Macintosh (or vice
>   versa) will work correctly with the
>   host Excel. When using this module's
>   xldate_as_tuple function to convert
>   numbers from a workbook, you must use
>   the datemode attribute of the Book
>   object. If you guess, or make a
>   judgement depending on where you
>   believe the workbook was created, you
>   run the risk of being 1462 days out of
>   kilter.
>
> Reference:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q180162
>
> (3) The Excel implementation of the
>   Windows-default 1900-based date system
>   works on the incorrect premise that
>   1900 was a leap year. It interprets
>   the number 60 as meaning 1900-02-29,
>   which is not a valid date.
>   Consequently any number less than 61
>   is ambiguous. Example: is 59 the
>   result of 1900-02-28 entered directly,
>   or is it 1900-03-01 minus 2 days? The
>   OpenOffice.org Calc program "corrects"
>   the Microsoft problem; entering
>   1900-02-27 causes the number 59 to be
>   stored. Save as an XLS file, then open
>   the file with Excel -- you'll see
>   1900-02-28 displayed.
>
> Reference:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;214326

which I quote here because the answer to your question is likely to be wrong unless you take that into account.

So to put this into code would be something like:

```
import datetime
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("myfile.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
cell = sheet.cell(5, 19) # type, <class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>


if sheet.cell(5, 19).ctype == 3: # 3 means 'xldate' , 1 means 'text'
    ms_date_number = sheet.cell_value(5, 19) # Correct option 1
    ms_date_number = sheet.cell(5, 19).value # Correct option 2

    year, month, day, hour, minute, second = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(ms_date_number, 
        book.datemode)
    py_date = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, nearest_second)
```

which gives you a Python datetime in `py_date` that you can do useful operations upon using the standard [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module.

I've never used xlrd, and my example is completely made up, but if there is a `myfile.xls` and it really has a date number in cell F20, and you aren't too fussy about precision as noted above, this code should work.

Comment: Not bad for somebody who's never used xlrd before. One remaining problem: It doesn't actually work; `sheet.cell(5, 19)` returns a `Cell` object, not a value. See my edit.

Comment: just having noticed the xlrd author: 'twas the quality of the documentation that allowed me to write a sample that *nearly* worked. Kudos.

Comment: You can also do `dt = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(ms_date_number, book.datemode)`  then `py_date = datetime(*dt)` to automatically unpack the tuple.

Answer (score 12):

The documentation of the function (minus the list of possible exceptions):

> xldate_as_tuple(xldate, datemode) [#]
>
> ```
> Convert an Excel number (presumed to represent a date, a datetime or a
> time) into a tuple suitable for feeding to datetime or mx.DateTime
> constructors.
>
> xldate
>     The Excel number
> datemode
>     0: 1900-based, 1: 1904-based.
>     WARNING: when using this function to interpret the contents of
>     a workbook, you should pass in the Book.datemode attribute of that
>     workbook. Whether the workbook has ever been anywhere near a Macintosh is
>     irrelevant. 
> Returns:
>     Gregorian (year, month, day, hour, minute, nearest_second).
> ```

As the author of xlrd, I'm interested in knowing how the documentation can be made better. Could you please answer these:

Did you read the general section on dates (quoted by @msw)?
Did you read the above specific documentation of the function?
Can you suggest any improvement in the documentation?
Did you actually try running the function, like this:

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(39274.0, 0)
(2007, 7, 11, 0, 0, 0)
>>> xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(39274.0 - 1.0/60/60/24, 0)
(2007, 7, 10, 23, 59, 59)
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it as [such](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function):

```
number = 39274.0
book_datemode = my_book.datemode
year, month, day, hour, minute, second = xldate_as_tuple(number, book_datemode)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime as dt
import xlrd

log_dir = 'C:\\Users\\'
infile = 'myfile.xls'
book = xlrd.open_workbook(log_dir+infile)
sheet1 = book.sheet_by_index(0)
date_column_idx = 1

## iterate through the sheet to locate the date columns
for rownum in range(sheet1.nrows):
    rows = sheet1.row_values(rownum)

    ## check if the cell is a date; continue otherwise
    if sheet1.cell(rownum, date_column_idx).ctype != 3 :
        continue

    install_dt_tuple = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple((rows[date_column_idx ]), book.datemode)

    ## the "*date_tuple" will automatically unpack the tuple. Thanks mfitzp :-)
    date = dt.datetime(*date_tuple)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I use to automatically convert dates:

```
cell = sheet.cell(row, col)
value = cell.value
if cell.ctype == 3:  # xldate
    value = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(value, workbook.datemode))
```