# How to convert from Python date to Excel date using xlrd (attribute xlrd.xldate_from_date_tuple does not exist)

Tags: python, excel, date, xlrd

How to convert from Python date to Excel date using xlrd module? [How to convert a python datetime.datetime to excel serial date number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574793/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-datetime-to-excel-serial-date-number) suggests a 'manual' solution, I wonder if it is the best way.

[Xlrd document](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html) suggests to use `xlrd.xldate_from_date_tuple`

but

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> xlrd.xldate_from_date_tuple
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xldate_from_date_tuple'
```

Could you help? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727916/xldate-as-tuple

Comment: I am looking for the opposite of xlrd_as_tuple. This one works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xlrd.xldate.xldate_from_date_tuple`